# Memory leaks when inserting data into sqlite database?

Tags: memory-leaks, sqlite

I have a simple sqlite function with SQLiteCpp as below on buildroot linux, it insert one row into database and will be called per second so I kept the database open. I found the memory usage keep on increasing, is it because I kept the database open? Should I close it every second? --Thanks

```
bool Sdb::InsertData(const Data* data)
{ 
  std::vector<std::string> tags = data->GetTags();

  try {
    SQLite::Statement query(mDb, "INSERT INTO test (serial_no, generation, consumption) VALUES ('01', 0, 0);");
    query.exec();
  } catch (std::exception& e) {std::cout << "exception happened: " << std::endl;
return false;
  }
std::cout << serial_no << " " << timestamp << " "
          << generation << " " << sqlite3_memory_used() << std::endl;
return true;
```

}

Comment: You have a leak only if there is allocated memory that can no longer be accessed. Why do you think that this is the case? (When inserting, the database and the cache will grow.)

Comment: "is it because I kept the database open?" -- you can check trivially to see if this is the case by, as you suggest, closing the connection to see if that helps..